# Why my bar plot isn't in descending order while my data has been set in descending order with sort_values ? (with pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, plot

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Species":x,"Images":y})
df = df.sort_values("Images",ascending=False)
print(df)

bar_width=1000


plt.clf()
plt.bar("Species","Images",data=df,width=bar_width)
plt.xlabel("Species",size="15")
plt.ylabel("Number of Images",size="15")
plt.title("Number of images for each species")
plt.show()
```

I would like to plot the number of images for each species in descending order. So I used `df = df.sort_values("Images",ascending=False)`
And indeed, when I print df, the values are in descending order :

```
204   1363227.0  **6812.0**
11    1356022.0  **5780.0**
240   1364099.0  **5039.0**
4     1355937.0  **4909.0**
112   1359517.0  **4761.0**
...         ...     ...
489   1394502.0     **1.0**
938   1440412.0     **0.0**
757   1412445.0     **0.0**
1058  1663341.0     **0.0**
846   1419924.0     **0.0**
```

But then the bar plot isn't in descending order. Would someone know how to fix this please ?
Have a good day.

EDIT : I put

```
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

and changed

```
plt.bar("Species","Images",data=df,width=bar_width)
```

to

```
plt.bar(df.index,"Images",data=df,width=bar_width)
```

and it worked. Thank you very much.

Comment: Please don't post images of code, data, or Tracebacks. Copy and paste it as text then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`) ...
[Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)...[Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) ... 
[You should not post code as an image because:...](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2823755)

Comment: You might need to reset the index after sorting.

Comment: previous comment is right if you are using index as the axis

Answer (score 0):

Since you have already sorted your DataFrame, just plot the `images` Series and change the xtick labels - the bars will be plotted in their Series order.

Here is one way to do it.

```
df.images.plot.bar()
locs,labels = plt.xticks()
plt.xticks(locs,df.species)
plt.show()
```

Here is another way to do it - Series.plot returns the matplotlib Axes which you can use to set the xtick labels to whatever you want.

```
ax = df.images.plot.bar()
ax.set_xticklabels(df.species)
```

---

The DataFrame

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'species': {0: 1363227.0, 1: 1356022.0, 2: 1364099.0, 3: 1355937.0, 4: 1359517.0,
                               5: 1394502.0, 6: 1440412.0, 7: 1412445.0, 8: 1663341.0, 9: 1419924.0},
                    'images': {0: 6812.0, 1: 5780.0, 2: 5039.0, 3: 4909.0, 4: 4761.0, 5: 1.0,
                               6: 0.0, 7: 0.0, 8: 0.0, 9: 0.0}})
```

---

[pyplot.xticks](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html#matplotlib.pyplot.xticks)
[pandas.Series.plot](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.plot.html?#pandas-series-plot)
[matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticklabels](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticklabels.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticklabels)